# Django Css file unresponsive after first loading of webpage

Tags: html, css, django

I can't figure out why my `main.css` isn't loading in my django project. I am using skeleton boilerplate and trying to change the background color but nothing is happening. It is strange because when i run `python3 manage.py runserver` it will compute my first original `main.css` values i put in at the begining of my project, but when i alter my `main.css` values the webpage just shows my original values.

- First i create a `static` folder in my project (outside my app).
- I then add a css folder.
- I then add my `skeleton.css`, `normalise.css` and my `main.css`

In my `index.html` I link my static folder and I link my skeleton css files and my main css files in my head tags.

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/normalize.css' %}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/skeleton.css' %}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}"/>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>index</title>
</head>
```

perfect it makes sense so far. Now is where I get confused. I put in some code into my main.css to make background color values and play around with the layout etc.

```
body {
background: #505f73;
}

.container {
background: #FF0000;
margin-bottom: 50px;
margin-top: 50px;
padding: 25px;
text-align: center;
}
```

[image]

This is exactly what i originally wanted when i was just coding up the charts. but now I want to change it around so first thing i did was try to change the `background-color` in my `main.css`

```
body {
background: #631d18;
}
```

All i do is change the hex number but no change is seen on my webpage, expecting the background to change. However, I still get the result from my original values. I can actually delete everything in my `main.css` and reload the webpage and the page shows my original output (picture above).

Any ideas what's up with it?

note: in my settings.py I have already added:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join('static'),)
```

Please find attached my directory structure attached below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if your running in development server make sure your settings variable DEBUG is set to True,

```
#settings.py
DEBUG = True
```

Comment: @peter can you share your directory structure?

Comment: i have just added the structure

Comment: strange can you print this to see what is the directory path it shows -> STATICFILES_DIRS

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your static file (main.css) follow the file structure `yourproject/app/static/app/main.css`.

import your app in HTML as `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'app/main.css' %}"/>`

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem is. turns out its not how django loads the files, it is that the browser i was using (safari) stores the cache of the django website. i switched over to chrome now and it seems to be loading all the changes i am making in in the `main.css`. when i cleared the cache in safari swell it worked, but i dont want to ave to do that each time i want to test the site so for now i will stick with chrome.